# Automatically updating/styling TreeView's TreeCells when BooleanProperty is true in seperate TableView

Tags: javafx, treeview

What's the easiest way to have a TreeView's cells auto-refresh with a new style when a condition is met in a separate TableView?

I'm currently setting the TreeCells' styles in the updateItem() method in the TreeView cell factory, but this only fires off if the user adds or removes something in the TreeView. I want to be able to change the style of a given TreeCell if I check off all 3 checkboxes in a separate dialog box.

I'm currently able to monitor the number of checked checkboxes with a BooleanProperty and an IntegerProperty, but I have no idea how I'm supposed to "auto-update" or call a TreeView refresh when a TreeItem's Object's BooleanProperty changes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the style in the TreeCell whenever a boolean property on the value underlying the TreeCell is updated (via a binding).

[image: sample]

```
return new TreeCell<Message>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Message item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        styleProperty().unbind();

        if (empty || item == null || item.getText() == null) {
            setText(null);
            styleProperty.set(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.getText());
            styleProperty().bind(
                    Bindings.when(
                            item.readProperty()
                    ).then("-fx-background-color: red;")
                            .otherwise("-fx-background-color: null;")
            );
        }
    }
};
```

*Full Sample*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TreeViewSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<Message> messages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        TreeItem<Message> rootItem = new TreeItem<> (new Message("Inbox"));
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            Message message = new Message("Message" + i);
            messages.add(message);
            TreeItem<Message> item = new TreeItem<> (message);
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        }        
        TreeView<Message> tree = new TreeView<> (rootItem);
        tree.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<Message>, TreeCell<Message>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeCell<Message> call(TreeView<Message> param) {
                return new TreeCell<Message>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Message item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        styleProperty().unbind();

                        if (empty || item == null || item.getText() == null) {
                            setText(null);
                            styleProperty.set(null);
                        } else {
                            setText(item.getText());
                            styleProperty().bind(
                                    Bindings.when(
                                            item.readProperty()
                                    ).then("-fx-background-color: red;")
                                            .otherwise("-fx-background-color: null;")
                            );
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });


        TableView<Message> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Message, String> textCol = new TableColumn<>("Text");
        textCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("text"));
        tableView.getColumns().add(textCol);

        TableColumn<Message, Boolean> readCol = new TableColumn<>("Read");
        readCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("read"));
        readCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(readCol));
        readCol.setEditable(true);
        tableView.getColumns().add(readCol);

        tableView.setItems(messages);

        VBox root = new VBox(10, tree, tableView);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        stage.show();
    }

    public class Message {
        private StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private BooleanProperty read = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        public Message(String msgText) {
            text.set(msgText);
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text.get();
        }

        public StringProperty textProperty() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text.set(text);
        }

        public boolean isRead() {
            return read.get();
        }

        public BooleanProperty readProperty() {
            return read;
        }

        public void setRead(boolean read) {
            this.read.set(read);
        }
    }
}
```

> I'm trying to the bind the graphicProperty to the same BooleanProperty and change the image based on the value.

Example using a binding of an Image within an ImageView associated with the cell.

[image: image binding]

```
Image unreadImage = new Image("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/16/Status-mail-unread-new-icon.png");
Image readImage = new Image("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/16/Messaging-Read-Message-icon.png");

. . . 

return new TreeCell<Message>() {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Message item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        styleProperty().unbind();
        imageView.imageProperty().unbind();

        if (empty || item == null || item.getText() == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
            styleProperty().set(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.getText());
            setGraphic(imageView);
            imageView.imageProperty().bind(
                    Bindings.when(
                            item.readProperty()
                    ).then(readImage)
                            .otherwise(unreadImage)
            );
            styleProperty().bind(
                    Bindings.when(
                            item.readProperty()
                    ).then("-fx-background-color: red;")
                            .otherwise("-fx-background-color: null;")
            );
        }
    }
};
```

An alternate (and possibly preferable) way to handle this from above is to instead get the style class or [psuedoclass](http://www.guigarage.com/2016/02/javafx-and-css-pseudo-classes/) of the cell and update that based upon the boolean property.  Then define the style in a separate CSS stylesheet.  The output of the sample below is the same as the graphic based sample above.

*mail.css*

```
.readable:read {
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-graphic: url(
        "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/16/Messaging-Read-Message-icon.png"
    );
}

.readable:unread {
    -fx-graphic: url(
        "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/16/Status-mail-unread-new-icon.png"
    );
}
```

Pseudo-class based code snippet:

```
PseudoClass READ_PSEUDO_CLASS = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("read");
PseudoClass UNREAD_PSEUDO_CLASS = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unread");
tree.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<Message>, TreeCell<Message>>() {
    @Override
    public TreeCell<Message> call(TreeView<Message> param) {
        return new TreeCell<Message>() {
            private ChangeListener<Boolean> readChangeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                pseudoClassStateChanged(READ_PSEUDO_CLASS, newValue);
                pseudoClassStateChanged(UNREAD_PSEUDO_CLASS, !newValue);
            };

            Message priorItem = null;

            {
                getStyleClass().add("readable");
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Message item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (priorItem != null) {
                    priorItem.readProperty().removeListener(readChangeListener);
                }

                priorItem = item;

                if (empty || item == null || item.getText() == null) {
                    setText(null);
                    pseudoClassStateChanged(READ_PSEUDO_CLASS, false);
                    pseudoClassStateChanged(UNREAD_PSEUDO_CLASS, false);
                } else {
                    item.readProperty().addListener(readChangeListener);
                    setText(item.getText());
                    pseudoClassStateChanged(READ_PSEUDO_CLASS, item.isRead());
                    pseudoClassStateChanged(UNREAD_PSEUDO_CLASS, !item.isRead());
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is just what I needed! Thank you, this has been driving me crazy.

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind. I'm trying to the bind the graphicProperty to the same BooleanProperty and change the image based on the value. I'm not sure what the parameters would be for the then() or otherwise() methods however:

`graphicProperty().bind(
       Bindings.when(
       item.readProperty()).then( *what goes here* ).otherwise( * and here *));`

I believe it wants an ObservableObjectProperty<T>. I'm not sure how to tie that to an ImageView.